# Radio Button bundle

Tags: java, android

I want to check that if my radio button is checked than on another activity it should use local ip and if my radio button is not checked then it should use ip provided by user i m doing it through bundle. I used following code but if condition is giving error `Required boolean` `Found java.lang.String` so how could i do this thing. I m beginner in Android Studio so don't know much.

Following is the code i used:

**SelectRoomActivity**

```
if(rb.isChecked()){
    rb.setChecked(true);
    SelectRoomActivity.bundle.putString("local","true");
}else{
    rb.setChecked(false);
    SelectRoomActivity.bundle.putString("local","false");
}
```

**EntranceActivity**

```
if (SelectRoomActivity.bundle.getString("false")){   //error is generated if condition
        serverAdress = address;   //abc.ddns.net
    }
    else{
        serverAdress = lan;   //192.168.1.101
    }
```

Comment: You are passing String by the name `local`" and trying to get it in another activity by the name `false`. It will surely give an error.

Comment: If `SelectRoomActivity.bundle` is a static variable, that is a poor configuration for storing constants or configurations

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values

Comment: if you insist on using strings like this, at least change SelectRoomActivity.bundle.getString("false") to SelectRoomActivity.bundle.getString("local") to grab the right string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try that
In you'r code you'r put String into your bundle, you need to put boolean 
When you get your variable in Entrance Activity, the string used are the name of you'r Boolean in the bundle ("local", and no "false")

**SelectRoomActivity**

```
if(rb.isChecked()){
    rb.setChecked(true);
    SelectRoomActivity.bundle.putBoolean("local",true);
}
else{
    rb.setChecked(false);
    SelectRoomActivity.bundle.putBoolean("local",false);
}
```

**EntranceActivity**

```
if (SelectRoomActivity.bundle.getBoolean("local")){   //error is generated if condition
    serverAdress = address;   //abc.ddns.net
}
else{
    serverAdress = lan;   //192.168.1.101
}
```

Comment: this is a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
SelectRoomActivity.bundle.putString("local","true"); AND

SelectRoomActivity.bundle.putString("local","false");
```

TO

```
SelectRoomActivity.bundle.putBoolean("local",true); AND 

SelectRoomActivity.bundle.putBoolean("local",false);
```

And on NExt Activity

```
if (SelectRoomActivity.bundle.getBoolean("local")){  
        serverAdress = address;   //abc.ddns.net
    }
    else{
        serverAdress = lan;   //192.168.1.101
    }
```

Comment: Maybe to add a check if bundles are null might be a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

SelectRoomActivity

```
if(rb.isChecked()){
   rb.setChecked(true);
   SelectRoomActivity.bundle.putString("local","true");
}else{
   rb.setChecked(false);
   SelectRoomActivity.bundle.putString("local","false");
}
```

and in EntranceActivity

```
if (SelectRoomActivity.bundle.getString("local").equalsIgnoreCase("false")){   
   //error is generated if condition
    serverAdress = address;   //abc.ddns.net
}
else{
    serverAdress = lan;   //192.168.1.101
}
```